# How do you Print Json Object from Json Feed with Python?

Tags: python, json, search, element

I am new to python and Json and I have a question regarding getting values from the JSON file.

Let's say I have a JSON feed for fruits such as the one below:

```
{
   "Banana": {
    Vitamin: "A",
},
 "Apple": {
    Vitamin: "B",
},
"Orange": {
    Vitamin: "C",
    },
}
```

Let's say I want to print the object (in this case the fruits) that has the vitamin element "C"

I am loading the json file using:

```
    import utils 
    fruits= utils.load_json('feed.json')
```

and I am storing the vitamins element in a variable like so:

```
      for fruit in fruits:
           list_of_vitamins= fruits[fruit]['Vitamin']
```

I am using an if statement to see if "C" is available in the list of vitamins and it is:

```
     if ("C" in list_of_vitamins):
          print "yes"
```

This is working fine, but now I am trying to find away to see if "C" exists and if it does, print the object that holds "C", in this case, "*orange*"

So in the end I just want the code to search the JSON file for the vitamin C and print the fruit orange.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

fruits_json= json.load(open('feed.json'))
print fruits_json

for fruit in fruits_json:
  if fruits_json[fruit]["Vitamin"] == "C":
    print fruit
```

Comment: No problem! You can upvote and accept it if it worked!.

Comment: Sure! How can I do that? I am relatively new here :)

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to build a "reverse" tree:

```
from collections import defaultdict

fruits_by_vitamin = defaultdict(list) # if a key doesn't exist, set it to an
                                      # empty list

for fruit,data in fruits.items(): # on Python2, use iteritems()
    fruits_by_vitamin[data['Vitamin']].append(fruit)

print(fruits_by_vitamin['C'])
```

Comment: thanks @Burhan Khalid for your answer. I have a question. what is list in defaultdict(list)? Also, I didnt understand the for loop. can you please explain it? thanks a lot :)

Comment: `defaultdict` is a way to set a default value for a dictionary, if a key doesn't exist. In this example, I am setting a default value for any key that doesn't exist to a list. The for loop is just like yours, except instead of looping though the keys, you are looping the keys _and the value for that key_ at the same time. That's what `.items()` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
aDict=json.loads("your json content")
for k,v in aDict.iteritems():
    #print '%s:%s' % (k, v)
    if v['Vitamin']='C':
        print k
```